# How to get the remote server hg path?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc, hg-paths

I have created a remote repo to push my local changes over ssl. I did `hg showconfig --debug` to find my remote hg path but it's output is messy. Can someone point me how to exactly find it?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

`hg paths` gives the relationship between each path name and its url.

```
> hg paths
default = ssh://hg@example.org/repo
local = /local/path/to/repo
```

`hg paths <name>` gives the url for the name.

```
> hg paths default
ssh://hg@example.org/repo

> hg paths local
/local/path/to/repo
```

BTW, to get just the path names:

```
> hg paths -q
default
local
```

and `hg paths -q <name>` will always result in no output.

Comment: Some added info: `hg paths` (with no parameter) shows all URLs for any symbolic paths (shortcuts) you have defined in `~/.hgrc` combined with the paths identified in the `/.../<repo>/.hg/hgrc` file if you are in a specific local repository. I am using Mercurial 3.3. Not sure about older versions.